# Line Plot with standard deviation

Tags: r, line, linechart, standard-deviation

I want to create a line chart, with two lines that shows the standard deviation for each for each line. At the moment, I have a line chart, that shows the two lines.
My Code is this, Categories is the name for the x-axes, Result 1/2 are the Results and SD 1/2 is the standard deviation.

```
categories <-c("Traditionsbewusst / Heimatverbunden","Bekanntheit
+ ","Jugendlich / Modern
+ ","Professionell
+ ","Sozial engagiert
+ ","Aufstrebend / Motiviert
+ ","Umwelt / Nachhaltigkeit
+ ","Sympathisch
+ ","Familienfreundlich
+ ","Mitreißend
+ ","Posetives Image
+ ","Teamgeist
+ ","Inovativ
+ ")


Result1<-c(2.34,1.76,2.66,2.85,2.45,2.66,2.64,2.89,2.61,2.80,2.94,2.72,2.82)
Result2<-c(2.08,1.29,2.41,2.39,2.11,2.08,2.34,2.25,2.19,2.24,2.58,2.19,2.42)

SD1<-c(0.89,0.93,0.85,0.92,0.78,0.86,0.86,1.01,0.83,0.86,0.92,0.90,0.97)
SD2<-c(0.96,0.71,0.80,0.85,0.89,1.00,0.76,0.94,0.87,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.85)

par(mar = c(15, 3, 3, 3))
plot(Result1,type = "b",main = "Profil Image",xlab = "",ylab = "Bewertung",axes =FALSE,ylim = c(1,4))
axis(1,at=1:13,labels = categories,las=2,cex.axis=0.8)
lines(Result2,type = "b")
axis(2)
```

Comment: Off-Topic: I think there is a misspelling: "posetives Image" should be "positives Image" and "Inovativ" should be "Innovativ".

Comment: Please explain your desired output again. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: No Problem, I want to add standard error bars

Comment: You want both line plots in one graph and both line plots with error bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrows, [see this post too](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html). If you put them on the same graph, it looks really bad:

```
par(mar = c(15, 3, 3, 3))
plot(Result1,type = "b",main = "Profil Image",xlab = "",ylab = "Bewertung",axes =FALSE,ylim = c(0,4))
arrows(x0=1:length(SD1), y0=Result1-SD1, x1=1:length(SD1),code=3,y1=Result1+SD1,angle=90, length=0.05)
arrows(x0=1:length(SD2), y0=Result2-SD2, x1=1:length(SD2),code=3,y1=Result2+SD2,angle=90, length=0.05)
axis(1,at=1:13,labels = categories,las=2,cex.axis=0.8)
lines(Result2,type = "b")
axis(2)
```

[image]

Maybe put them side by side:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
par(mar = c(15, 3, 3, 3))
plot(Result1,type = "b",main = "Profil Image",xlab = "",ylab = "Bewertung",axes =FALSE,ylim = c(0,4))
arrows(x0=1:length(SD1), y0=Result1-SD1, x1=1:length(SD1),code=3,y1=Result1+SD1,angle=90, length=0.05)
axis(1,at=1:13,labels = categories,las=2,cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2)

plot(Result2,type = "b",main = "Profil Image",xlab = "",ylab = "Bewertung",axes =FALSE,ylim = c(0,4))
arrows(x0=1:length(SD2), y0=Result2-SD2, x1=1:length(SD2),code=3,y1=Result2+SD2,angle=90, length=0.05)
axis(1,at=1:13,labels = categories,las=2,cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

StupidWolf already answered your question, but I want to show you an alternative approach for plotting your data using `ggplot2`, `tidyr` and `dplyr`. They are all included in the package `tidyverse`.

First we need to create an data.frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(categories, Result1, Result2, SD1, SD2)
                            categories Result1 Result2  SD1  SD2
1  Traditionsbewusst / Heimatverbunden    2.34    2.08 0.89 0.96
2                          Bekanntheit    1.76    1.29 0.93 0.71
3                  Jugendlich / Modern    2.66    2.41 0.85 0.80
4                        Professionell    2.85    2.39 0.92 0.85
5                     Sozial engagiert    2.45    2.11 0.78 0.89
```

Now we need to tidy up the data a bit, bringing it into a "long" format:

```r
df %<>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("Result"), names_to="Group", names_prefix="Result", values_to="Result") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("SD"), names_to="SD_Group", names_prefix="SD", values_to="SD") %>%
  filter(Group == SD_Group) %>%
  select(-SD_Group)

# A tibble: 26 x 4
   categories                          Group Result    SD
   <chr>                               <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Traditionsbewusst / Heimatverbunden 1       2.34  0.89
 2 Traditionsbewusst / Heimatverbunden 2       2.08  0.96
 3 Bekanntheit                         1       1.76  0.93
 4 Bekanntheit                         2       1.29  0.71
 5 Jugendlich / Modern                 1       2.66  0.85
```

Now there is a variable `Group`, that separates Result1, SD1 and Result2, SD2. The values of Result and SD are presented in the column `Result` and `SD`. Data in this kind of presentation is usally easier to be worked with.

Now we are using `ggplot` to create the plot. `ggplot` provides many possibilities for plotting data at the cost of a complex syntax.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=categories, y=Result, group=Group, color=Group)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Result-SD, ymax=Result+SD)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 1, hjust = 1), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  ylim(c(0,4.5)) +
  labs(title="Profil Image", 
       x=NULL, 
       y="Bewertung",
       color="Gruppe") +
  facet_wrap(~Group, labeller=labeller(Group=paste0("Gruppe ", 1:2)))
```

gives

[image: ggplot_of_categories_vs_rating_per_group]

Comment: Thanks a lot.
That must be fate because I'm trying to work more with ggplot.